# Change iOS app name in code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to change the name of my app **only as it appears on the user's home screen**. The old app name can remain in place on the App Store, in iTunes Connect, in Xcode, wherever else. I want to make this change **only for certain users**. When the **code determines conditions are met**, the user's app name should change. Is it possible to do this and if so, how?

**EDIT:**

To clarify my reason, this is for a game where a "deep secret" of the game would be hinted at by the game's title. I want to hide the hint by using an acronym for the title until the player has revealed the secret in-game. At which point I would change the app's title to reveal the full game title.

Comment: i Don't think its possible @peacetype

Comment: Sorry. It's not possible. There is no way to change your app name only for some of your users.

Comment: This isn't possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but even if it were technically possible, I'm sure Apple would object to it being potentially misleading (your app's name and icon effectively **identifiy** it to the eyes of the user). Perhaps you can make do with notification badges in the app's icon?

Comment: It is not possible to change at runtime. 

App name is stored at CFBundleDisplayName  and you cannot modify your bundle at runtime

Answer (score 4):

Afaik you can only change the display name in your `...-Info.plist` file. However, you can have different display names for your app by localising that file, but that would only give you different names based on the language, not the user.

For more Information see [Updating the display name of your app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1823/_index.html)

**What you can do:**

Option 1: Setup different schemes for each user environments and compile one app for each possible type of user

Option 2: Create an app internal home screen and let the user select the more specific app there

Option 3: Don't change the display name, but change the color schemes and logos in the app (I have seen this in some apps)

Comment: Wow, those are some very creative options! Not sure if any would quite fit my situation. But it could come in handy for other situations where you need different variations of your app name for different kinds of users. So far it seems like it's not possible to do exactly what I want. But I'll keep your suggestions in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I believe Apple strongly discourages Option 2: Apps that behave like a "launcher", with their own "Home screen" and (child) app "icons".