# Change react-native app display name programatically

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile

there. How can i change react-native app display name programatically ? Is there any way ? I use bare workflow. I want to change app display name at runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change display name of an app in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580858/how-to-change-display-name-of-an-app-in-react-native)

Comment: It's not possible to change app name programmatically.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7607769/5793132
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47030080/5793132

Comment: @mkaatman It doesn't work. I am trying to find to reach ios infoPlist PRODUCT_NAME and update  programatically.

Comment: @UğurEren If I can reach to ios info plist  I hope I can change app name.

Comment: I guess you need to understand IOS app fundamentals. info.plist is not something you can change during runtime. info.plist is used by xcode to prepare your application, it is used at compile-time, not runtime.

Comment: @UğurEren Yes, you are right.